# How to generate SSL certificate?

Tags: ssl

i am following instructions to resolve the iOS 9 related issue for SSL. there are steps where we need to provide self signed certificate ssl_cert.p12 and ca.crt.

my query is how can i generate this certificate ssl_cert.p12 and ca.crt
i have IBM websphere 8.5.5 network deployment and linux operation system

Comment: You can use openssl in any linux machine to generated such certificate

Comment: This question is general and does not actually relate to IBM MobileFirst: search online how to generate certificates. For example: http://i-proving.com/2008/08/07/how-to-generateuse-openssl-ssl-certificates-for-web-servers-and-use-them-in-a-java-key-store-or-ikeyman-database/