# Create and configure Self Signed CA certificate on IBM websphere network deploy 8.6 for iOS9

Tags: ios, websphere, self-signed

currently IBM WebSphere network deployment 8.6 is configured with default self signed certificate and keystore (key.p12 and trust.p12) while accessing from iOS 9 device , it's unable to communicate on https and throws the error. some article shows that ioS will work with self signed CA certificate so would like to know how can i create such certificate and configure it on the websphere server?

OS : Linux

Comment: Don't duplicate your question. Your question IS NOT RELATED to MobileFirst: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38591467/how-to-generate-ssl-certificate

Comment: i am looking for Self signed CA certificate and also i am looking for how to configure on websphere

Comment: IBM Documentation: [Creating a self-signed certificate](https://www.ibm.com/support/knowledgecenter/SSAW57_8.5.5/com.ibm.websphere.nd.doc/ae/tsec_sslcreateselfsigncert.html) & [Default chained certificate configuration in SSL](https://www.ibm.com/support/knowledgecenter/en/SSAW57_8.5.5/com.ibm.websphere.nd.doc/ae/csec_7ssldefault_chainedcert_config.html). This should help with the WebSphere-side configuration.